# are there side effects of running jest with --detectOpenHandles --forceExit?

Tags: javascript, tdd, integration-testing, jestjs

I'm using `jest` for testing, and in a few test scenarios I get the `jest` message:

`Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.`
While taking Jest's recommendation to run with `--detectOpenHandles` and ending up with hanging test process that never ends, I saw other online suggestions to add the `--forceExit` option as well. Now the test ends and everything is ok.

It worths mentioning that all the tests are running properly and passing, with or without the `--detectOpenHandles --forceExit` options.

I wonder if is that considered as best practice in such cases? or is it just serving me as a "first aid"?
What are the side effects of doing so?

Cheers,

Comment: Best practice would be close those handles in your tests, so you don't have to deal with them afterwards. Maybe the tests are running "properly", but that doesn't mean they are properly programmed.

Comment: Most useful answer-ish I've found is https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1456

Comment: @Vadorequest so if I understand the thread correctly, the `forceExit` flag won't wait promises (whether they were resolved or rejected)? 
again, pls correct me, its a long thread so maybe I missed something

Comment: Yeah, I believe it's something like that, I'm no expert but it seems to kill whatever is pending by closing the current process, at the cost of not making you aware it did that. The correct way is to properly close connections yourself when tests are done, but in my case I was unable to understand what was not closing properly (and it's very hard to debug) so I used the --forceExit option to force my CI tests to terminate the process so that the coverage report can be sent. (otherwise it considers it's still waiting something and never send coverage report, which breaks my CI)

Comment: @Vadorequest yeah same here... CI was never done and my team and I could not debug what open connections/processes are still running

Comment: Yup, very similar indeed. Here is my CI script (node) `"test:coverage": "NODE_ENV=test yarn sls:dotenv && yarn delete:redis ; yarn start:redis:daemon && jest --coverage --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit && yarn stop:redis"` if that helps. I couldn't figure out what `detectOpenHandles` actually does, but decided to let it there to avoid warnings about not using --forceExit without it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the documentation, the `detectOpenHandles` option is for:

> Attempt to collect and print open handles preventing Jest from exiting cleanly. Use this in cases where you need to use --forceExit in order for Jest to exit to potentially track down the reason. This implies --runInBand, making tests run serially. Implemented using async_hooks, so it only works in Node 8 and newer. This option has a significant performance penalty and should only be used for debugging.

The `forceExit` option should never be used as a best practice, the only time you have to use is because:

- An async function did not finish
- A promise function did not finish
- A Websocket connection is still open
- A Database connection is still open
- Everything having a connect/disconnect methods did not disconnect before the end of the test

Comment: so that implies that using both `--detectOpenHandles --forceExit ` is almost useless unless using with `--runInBand`, correct?

Comment: True :) The `--runInBand` option is different, this is an option to serially run the tests (nothing to do with `--detectOpenHandles` & `--forceExit`)

Comment: What I understand from the documentation is that `--runInBand` is implicit when using `--forceExit`, so specify it or not should make no difference, but maybe there is something I misunderstood.